# IFR layer-> Unity-> Reference to ApplicationUser in CORE

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, unity-container

I have just began with unity and I have this problem.

I have the layer IFR, my all layers have reference to it (IFR) for this reason can no create the containers like this:

```
 container.RegisterType<IAddressManager, AddressManager>();
```

The solution is:

```
container.RegisterType(Type.GetType("ShoppingTool.CORE.Contracts.IAddressManager, ShoppingTool.CORE"),  
                Type.GetType("ShoppingTool.APP.AddressManager, ShoppingTool.APP"));
```

But my problem is with this three containers for de UserManager.

```
 container.RegisterType<AccountController>(new InjectionConstructor());
    container.RegisterType<ManageController>(new InjectionConstructor());
    container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>();
```

Note: ApplicationUser is in the CORE layer.

I dont'n know how to traslate the reference of this containers without reference.
I have to put the UnityConfig in the IFR layer and all layers have to access to this layer because I'm using log4net and email function.
Note: is a mandatory of the subject.
Thanks in adavance for your help.

Comment: You'd only register Unity in the composition root -- usually where your application starts up. What exactly is the error you are receiving?

Comment: At the end I could resolve the issue with this code.  container.RegisterType(Type.GetType("ShoppingTool.MVC.Controllers.AccountController, ShoppingTool.MVC"), new InjectionConstructor());

            container.RegisterType(Type.GetType("ShoppingTool.MVC.Controllers.ManageController, ShoppingTool.MVC"), new InjectionConstructor()); But up to now I can't resolve the last one: container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>();

Comment: I don't understand your question or problem. You add a `using Namespace.CORE` and if you can `new ApplicationUser()` or `new UserStore()` then the container should be able to manage the instances for your application.